# Redis cluster in redis compose without using defaul port

Tags: docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I´m new at redis cluster

I'm starting a redis cluster with a docker compose configuration.
I not using default redis ports
redis-cli --cluster create 173.18.0.2:1002 173.18.0.3:1003 173.18.0.4:1004 173.18.0.5:1005 173.18.0.6:1006 173.18.0.7:1007 --cluster-replicas 1

It looks that master instances start in a correct way but slaves looks like are not enable to connect to master ones because try to use default ports instead the ones configured in cluster created command

docker compose up output where I thiks is the problem

redis_4            | 1:S 03 Apr 2023 14:22:46.342 * Before turning into a replica, using my own master parameters to synthesize a cached master: I may be able to synchronize with the new master with just a partial transfer.

redis_4            | 1:S 03 Apr 2023 14:22:46.342 * Connecting to MASTER 173.18.0.4:6379

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide any examples of your docker-compose file, so I can only suggest you to try my implementation for your problem:

```
services:
  redis-1002:
    image: redis:6.2
    command: ["redis-server", "--cluster-enabled", "yes", "--cluster-config-file", "nodes.conf", "--cluster-node-timeout", "5000", "--appendonly", "yes", "--protected-mode", "no", "--port", "1002"]
    ports:
      - "1002:1002"

  redis-1003:
    image: redis:6.2
    command: ["redis-server", "--cluster-enabled", "yes", "--cluster-config-file", "nodes.conf", "--cluster-node-timeout", "5000", "--appendonly", "yes", "--protected
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).